# NSString to char[] in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, char

I have to convert a NSString to a null ended char[].

The way Im doing it is like this:

```
NSString *regC = @"1234"    
char REG[[regC length] +1];
BOOL result = [regC getCString:REG maxLength:32 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and I dont know if is it the correct way.

REG has to be a 5 chars array, with a null in the last one/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to convert as long as you use ASCII characters in your NSString. They are representer as single byte characters in UTF-8 encoding.
If you use some non-ASCII characters you should make your REG bigger.

Upd: one more: you should put your actual buffer size into "maxLength:" parameter in order to avoid buffer overrun. Not 32 but [regC length] +1.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *REG = [@"test" UTF8String];
```

You can't allocate the length of a char[] at runtime unless you use malloc/free. but with the above way you won't need to manage memory.